# Hierarchical clustering parallel processing in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, hpc, hierarchical-clustering

Is there straightforward method to take advantage of parallel processing in R within a HPC cluster to make my computations faster for Hierarchical clustering algorithm? Because right now, the average utilization of processors is just 1 though i can request and utilize many more. Thanks.

Comment: See the [snow](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/snow/index.html) package

Comment: @copeg would yo be able to give a sample of the snow package or link a straightfoward sample code of it?

Comment: @Adam, the [snow simplified](http://www.sfu.ca/~sblay/R/snow.html) page has some descent examples. The snow reference PDF in the link above is worth a look as well. Hard to entertain how to use for clustering in the original question without more information

Comment: I will look into the documentation before i ask follow up questions. Thank you for this! And regarding more information, i have a matrix of dimension of approx 84000x5000(5000 features with 84k instances) that i want to use hclustering. Just want to figure out a method to reduce the time for distance computation.

Comment: @Kraamed see the function Dist in R package amap (amap::Dist). This allows parallelisation. Argument nbproc gives the number of sub-processes to run (== number of cores). http://svitsrv25.epfl.ch/R-doc/library/amap/html/dist.html

Comment: I didn't realise this was such an old question! Anyway, I hope the comment helps someone.